# How to detect where in the layout files addItem was used?

Tags: module, layout

I don't like the default Magento combine js / css feature. It just clumps up the entire page of js and css into one file on a per-page basis. This results in pages that have one additional css resource generating a new css file - 90% of which *should* be cached by the client and not downloaded AGAIN as part of this new css file.

What I am wanting to do is *intelligently* combine js and css files, so the default head addJs / addItem actions are grouped into one file, then any additional page-specific js is grouped into another file.

How do I detect what layout block (e.g. default) the action addItem was being called from?

Alternatively, if there is an extension that does this then I would be interested in the pre-built solution (I haven't found one).

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky and I don't have a solution, but some hints: The layout handles (this is the term for what you called "layout block") are loaded and **merged** in `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update` **before** they are processed. This means, at the moment where `addAction` is called, it comes from one big XML tree of blocks and actions without the handles and there is no way to find out where it comes from.

So I could only imagine a solution with an extended layout model, where you preprocess the XML coming from the default handle before it is merged. Then you could for example add an additional parameter to `addCss` actions, `$fromDefault = true` - of course you have to extend `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` as well to process this parameter somehow.

Comment: I have thought I will be needing to add a flag to the add functions. I was kinda hoping now to, as it would allow any extensions I install to work out of the box without me going through the layouts adding the extra parameter. And if I can get this to work as I want it, I might even pop it on the extensions site where other people may not know *how* to add the extra params.

Comment: What if I turn this around, and do the merge thing last? In the admin panel pull out a list of all css / js that is being added to the head on the homepage so that the admin may select what to combine / merge on ALL pages, then do something like str_replace to remove the selected css / js from the generated response, and add the combined css / js urls to the head? Actually, that feels very very hacky and I feel dirty just for thinking it. But I am open to alternative suggestions?

Comment: Probably still a better approach than what I suggested. You could use your own code to read the merged layout XML (not the merged updates for a particular site) to find out which files are added in the `default` handle, cache this information and use it for the merged files. Then you can either remove the files that have been merged from the response using an observer or rewrite `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addItem()` to not do anything if the given file is in the list.